# Null Pointer on Autowired JavaMailSender

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, jakarta-mail

Why would this throw a Null-pointer exception for the variable
private static JavaMailSender when I use it at "sender.createMimeMessage()"?

I'm trying test just this method "SendTicketMail" which is why I declared it static (because my main needed it so) and likewise I needed to declare sender as static.

If that is the problem how can I test them without declaring sender or SendTicket as static?

```
package sof.eng.project.Tickets;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;

import soft.eng.project.Event.Event;
import soft.eng.project.Parent.Parent;
import soft.eng.project.Provider.Provider;

public class TicketsController {

    @Autowired
    private static JavaMailSender sender;

    static void SendTicketMail(Parent parent, Provider provider, Event event, int Tickets, int TotalPrice) throws MessagingException, DocumentException, IOException
            {
                MimeMessage mimeMessageObj = sender.createMimeMessage();
                MimeMessageHelper messageObj = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessageObj, true, "UTF-8");
               // messageObj.setFrom(fromEmail);
                messageObj.setTo(parent.getEmail());
                messageObj.setSubject("Your ticket for...");
                messageObj.setText("<strong>See The Attached</strong>", true);

                String firstName = parent.getFirstName();
                String lastName = parent.getLastName();
                String eventname = event.getTitle();
                String fileName = "tickets.pdf";

                PDFConfiguration.makePDF(fileName, firstName, lastName, eventname, Tickets, TotalPrice);


                byte[] data = null;
                try {
                    data = readFully(fileName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                messageObj.addAttachment(""+ eventname + "-Ticket.pdf", new ByteArrayResource(data));
            }

    public static byte[] readFully(String sourcePath) throws IOException
            {
                InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                return baos.toByteArray();
            }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, DocumentException, IOException 
    {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setFirstName("Max");
        parent.setLastName("Maximus");
        parent.setEmail("kanic123@gmail.com");
        parent.setPassword("asda");
        parent.setAddress("address");

        Provider provider = new Provider();
        provider.setFirstName("firstName");
        provider.setLastName("lastName");
        provider.setPassword("asda");
        provider.setCompanyName("asdaCorps");
        provider.setEmail("asda@gmail.com");
        provider.setBankAccount("123asda123");
        provider.setAddress("address Str");
        provider.setStatus("normal");

        Event event = new Event();
        event.setEmail("email");
        event.setTickets(1000);
        event.setPrice(10);
        event.setAddress("address");
        event.setMinAge(5);
        event.setMaxAge(15);
        event.setCategory("athletics");
        event.setTicketsLeft(100);
        event.setReleaseDate(null);
        event.setKickoffDate(null);
        event.setDescription("description");

        int Tickets = 10;
        int TotalPrice = 100;
        SendTicketMail(parent,provider,event,Tickets, TotalPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is throwing NPE in test case only or in code also?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but my console say this : 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sof.eng.project.Tickets.TicketsController.SendTicketMail(TicketsController.java:47)
 at sof.eng.project.Tickets.TicketsController.main(TicketsController.java:121)"

The line is different because of some  comments but it really is that "sender.createMimeMessage()"

Comment: In test case, you don't usually load the beans in container that is why it is giving NPE. You need to mock the member. Can I provide some example?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? I'm new to Spring and can't really catch what you are saying. An example would be great

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. where's you test code? Are you using junit? Could you share that with us please? Since you are using spring, you should not use static variable, but instance variables. If it's a bean it will be the same bean whereever you use it, so no need to define it static.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any frameworks for testing. I just ran that main method as "java app" through spring. From what I understood so far, and please correct me if I'm wrong, because I didn't run it as "SpringApplication.run(....)" it doesn't take into consideration my properties file and therefore my JavaMailSender isn't configured properly, which is why it doesn't get Autowired to anything(?)

Comment: I think you should read Spring documentation before create a test method. Your code has a lot of mistakes: Your TicketsController is not envolved by '@controller' or similar Spring annotation so your bean won't be instantiated by Spring. JavaMailSender should not be static. If you want to test your code you must create '@test' method class using Spring context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start Spring application context.
If you want to run a test, i recommend you to use JUnit and SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Comment: I managed to run it in Spring application context , I run that method as a typical controller method with it's own url. The same error applies :
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at soft.eng.project.Tickets.TicketsController.SendTicketMail(TicketsController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]